# SharePoint Online Add-In: Initialize List with DateTime Field: String was not recognized as a valid DateTime

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-addin, visual-studio, xml

I want to initialize a list in a SharePoint Online Add-in with the following XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
    <ListInstance Title="Punchlist Items" OnQuickLaunch="FALSE" TemplateType="100" Url="Lists/Punchlist Items" Description="">
      <Data>
        <Rows>
          <Row>
            <Field Name="Title">This is an open punchlist item</Field>
            <Field Name="PunchlistNumber">AHU0101-PL-0001</Field>
            <Field Name="Open">2015-01-02T00:00:00Z</Field>
            <Field Name="TypeId">1</Field>
            <Field Name="GMP">true</Field>
            <Field Name="ResponsibleId">1</Field>
            <Field Name="Closed"></Field>
          </Row>
        </Rows>
      </Data>
    </ListInstance>
  </Elements>
```

But I'm receiving an error:

> String was not recognized as a valid DateTime

When the `Closed` field is empty (it works fine if I give `Closed` a value like `2015-01-02T00:00:00Z`). Is there a way to create the row with an empty DateTime field? I don't want a value in the `Closed` field and it is not a required field.

Comment: Check by removing `Closed` field entry from your XML and see if it works.

Comment: That's it - thank you. If you post it as as an answer I'll accept

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the `Closed` field from that XML `Row` and you will no longer get the error mentioned and it will be stored as an empty.